# How to get exact 15 days before records not between

Tags: mysql

i have a table where next_due _date is a column and in that multiple dates are presented like 2019-09-14,2019-11-30,2019-09-14.

I want to write a query which i will execute on a daily bases which returns me  before 15 days data against next_due _date

Comment: Welcome! To ask [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), please read [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). **We are very willing to help you fix your code, but we don't write code for you.**

Comment: https://jlericson.com/2016/07/13/QA_economics.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query which will be useful to you.

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE SUBDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY ) < next_due _date
```

But you need other things too Because you need execution on a daily basis and sending those data back to you.

1 -For daily execution, you can use trigger from database which works as a scheduler for you but it can not send data back to though you can store data in another table and you might export them as CSV or text when you need.

2 If you want those data back to you in some format like text or excel and fully automated then you have to use some serverside language like PHP. You will write a script / API which will generate a file for you, even send via email. Here the endpoint you will must be run by some schedule from your system like crontab.

And there are many other ways also your requirements are not short.